# dotnet mvc relationships in post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have these tables: Sales, product, stock and salesProduct. I'm using a database first approach, they were created using EF scaffold. Sales table looks like this:

```
 public partial class Sales
    {
        public Sales()
        {
            SalesProduct = new HashSet<SalesProduct>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
        public bool IndActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SalesProduct> SalesProduct { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need the post method on sales creation to create a SalesProduct object and add it to the database. I also need it to update the stock of that specific product.
Here are the other tables:

```
 public partial class SalesProduct
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SaleId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public bool IndActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Produto IdProductNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual Vendum IdSalesNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}

public partial class Stock
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdProduct { get; set; }
        public int? Quantitu { get; set; }
        public bool IndActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Product IdProductNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

How can i do that? I'm confused on how to deal with entity relationships in http methods!

Comment: Just to be clear: **ASP.NET MVC** is a **web** framework - it has nothing to do with storing data in database tables and representing them in code. That would be the job of e.g. **Entity Framework** - those are two **totally different, separate** technologies - don't mix them up !

Comment: I don't understand, what it is you are trying to do exactly. But the basics are that you have to have DbContext instance with DbSet which represents your table in database. Then u can just create new instances of scaffoled objects (entities) and using DbContext and DbSet, you can add them to database using context.WantedDbSet.Add(yourEntity). If you have no idea what I am talking about learn more about it, keywords are entity framework, dbcontext, dbset... Or it is possible that I just misunderstood you, in that case, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Without the exit the exact code of what you are trying to do, one can only guess. You can either create a DTO which contains fields for both entities or add business logic to handle the post object